# The use of ReferenceArrayInput

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've an issue with `ReferenceArrayInput` that I try to use for a group membership representation.

Here the code related to a group editing UI

```
export const UserGroupEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit title={<UserGroupTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput label="Common Name" source="commonName" />
            <TextInput label="E-mail" source="email" type="email" />
            <TextInput label="Shortname (UNIX purpose)" source="shortname" />
            <ReferenceArrayInput label="Members" source="members" reference="users">
                 <SelectArrayInput optionText="fullName" />
            </ReferenceArrayInput>
            <DisabledInput label="Record UUID" source="id" />
            <DisabledInput label="Record ID" source="numericID" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

I've two issue.

First, if the related property in the represented object is empty, the UI does not display the input field. It show the title of the field, a whitespace with no input possible and the next one. When I pass the mouse over the whitespace, I get the same icon attached to the mouse as a `DisabledInput`, the forbidden sign.

Second, if there is already one value, I can add new one, I've the text input available and the autocompletion is working well. However, once I select one value to add, it immediately disappear. It does not stay in memory until the save or cancel action.

And if in the second case, I remove existing values, they get properly removed and once I remove everything I'm back to the first issue.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like an issue to me. Can you set up a codesandbox ? https://codesandbox.io/s/5xwv91v4n4

Comment: And sorry for my previous answer, I misread and mistyped XD

Answer (score 0):

About your first issue, you can try to add a `allowEmpty` prop to your `ReferenceArrayInput` :

```
<ReferenceArrayInput label="Members" source="members" reference="users" allowEmpty>
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed it solve the issue, I've missed this part in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug indeed. This issue has been fixed on master which will be released soon as version `1.4.0`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, I now need to understand how to setup my local project to rely on your git instead of public release, so I can continue to develop in the mean time ^^

Comment: This is explained at the end of the README :)